# Create javascript button for entering unicode character into form field

Tags: javascript, button, input, unicode, character

I wish to create a button for entering special unicode characters into an online form field. For example, I want people to write the chemical formula for oxygen - I want them to write O2 where the 2 is the unicode character 2082 (which looks like subscript 2 but isn't 2 formatted as <sub>2</sub> - I need it to be unicode rather than formatted as subscript for automated answer checking). So users would type O from the keyboard then click a button that has a small 2 on it to enter that unicode character at the cursor position. Can this be done with javascript/html?

Thanks to anyone who can help with code for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done with pure JavaScript. Here's a simple example:

```js
function addTwo() {
    var element = document.getElementById('textInput');
    var newString = element.value.slice(0, element.selectionStart) + '₂' + element.value.slice(element.selectionStart, element.value.length);
    element.value = newString;
}
```

```css
input, button {
    font-size: 36px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textInput" value="HO"/>

<button onClick="addTwo()">
    ₂
</button>

<p>
    Put your cursor between the H and the O and click the ₂ button.
</p>
```